# Basic jQuery on hyperlink clicked print content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping for a little guidance if possible. On my website I have a small area that shows "Most Popular" and underneath I have 4 hyperlinks: Blogs, Tips, News, Videos. I want it so that if the user clicks the hyperlink it prints the appropriate content below, ideally without loading the entire page but not essential.

I'm new to jQuery so if someone could help me that would be super.

Thank you.

Comment: This requires an AJAX call (unless all the content is preloaded), most easily done in this situation with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery's AJAX, especially the load method: http://api.jquery.com/load/

In a nutshell, this method makes a request to a URL, and writes the response into any element you specify. In your case, I would likely:

1) Create a URL which returns the HTML snippet you want to display e.g: 
`<div><p>Popular Blog 1</p><p>Popular Blog 2</p></div>`

2) In the javascript on your page, add something like this:

```
$("a#myPopularBlogsLink").click(function() {
    $("#loadAndReplaceContentInThisElement").load("http://mywebsite.com/some-url-returning-data/);
});
```

3) If you read through the jQuery docs, you may be able to adapt this better to your situation - for example, passing a parameter in the .load() method to choose which page you want to load data for, etc.

It's hard to say what the best practice would be without more details on your situation - how much flexibility you have server-side with URLs, how much control you have over your content, and if you  need search engines to index the content (they will NOT index content loaded through AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#alink").click(function () {
            $("#aframe").attr("src", $(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<a id="alink" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<div id="adiv">
    <iframe id="aframe" src="" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
```